# Complex function to plane with non-negative real axis removed must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if I have a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\backslash A$ where A is the non-negative real axis then $f$ must be constant.

My thoughts so far are to conformally map the negative real axis to the unit disc via a mobius transformation, and then argue something on Liouville's theorem, however I am having trouble putting this together, mapping the region conformally onto a bounded domain seems difficult.

Comment: Throw in a square root at the appropriate place.

Comment: @DanielFischer So $f = \sqrt z$ is holomorphic on the plane with the positive real axis removed, but doesn't it just map the plane to itself?

Comment: No, it doesn't map the (slit) plane to itself. It maps the slit plane to something you already know how to handle in this context. To see what, perhaps start by looking what becomes of $z = e^{it},\; 0 < t < 2\pi$.

Comment: Ah I see, so it maps it to a semi-circle which we can then conformally map to an open disc. Not sure why I assumed $\sqrt z$ mapped the plane to itself

Comment: No, not a semicircle. $\sqrt{z}$ maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ to a half-plane (whether the upper or lower half-plane depends on the chosen branch).

Comment: Oh yes of course, there is no restriction on $r$